# Pinescript line.new drawing two lines on the chart

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I am new to TradingView and hence Pinescript and hence trying to figure out various how to build an indicator script meeting my requirements.

- I want to create an indicator that draws Camarilla lines (based on Pivot) on my chart, irrespective of any timeframe I choose that is granular than Daily timeframe.
- I want the lines to be shown only for the current trading day i.e. I do not want the pivot lines to be plotted on my chart for any previous days except today.
- As I am based in India, I want the lines to appear only for the period 09:15am to 15:30pm.

Using some sample Camarilla examples found on TradingView and online and as well as the Pinescript tutorial, I have come-up with the following code. However, for each line.new, I am seeing two lines drawn on the chart. I am not sure why there are two lines in the first place when I only gave one combination of (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) co-ordinates

[Image: Camarilla Pivot Lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FROd7.jpg)

Can you please help me where I am doing it wrong and let me know the remedy to fix this issue.

```
//Created by GT

//@version=4
study(title="My Test Camarilla Setup", shorttitle="Camarilla", overlay=true)

showDailyPivots = input(true, title="Show Daily Pivots")

//Calculate Camarilla values
pivot = (high + low + close ) / 3.0 
range = high - low
h5 = (high/low) * close 
h4 = close + (high - low) * 1.1 / 2.0
h3 = close + (high - low) * 1.1 / 4.0
h2 = close + (high - low) * 1.1 / 6.0
h1 = close + (high - low) * 1.1 / 12.0
l1 = close - (high - low) * 1.1 / 12.0
l2 = close - (high - low) * 1.1 / 6.0
l3 = close - (high - low) * 1.1 / 4.0
l4 = close - (high - low) * 1.1 / 2.0
h6 = h5 + 1.168 * (h5 - h4) 
l5 = close - (h5 - close)
l6 = close - (h6 - close)

// Calculate x-axis variables to correspond to day's start time and end time.
// Here start time is hardcoded to 09:15am and endtime as 15:30pm (Timings for Indian Markets) 
// These will be used as part of line.new() statements to draw pivot lines on the chart
yearVar = year
monthVar = month
dayVar = dayofmonth
startTime = timestamp(syminfo.timezone,yearVar,monthVar,dayVar,09,15)
endTime = timestamp(syminfo.timezone,yearVar,monthVar,dayVar,15,30)

//Daily Pivots 
dtime_pivot = security(syminfo.ticker, 'D', pivot[1]) 
dtime_h6 = security(syminfo.ticker, 'D', h6[1]) 
dtime_h5 = security(syminfo.ticker, 'D', h5[1]) 
dtime_h4 = security(syminfo.ticker, 'D', h4[1]) 
dtime_h3 = security(syminfo.ticker, 'D', h3[1]) 
dtime_h2 = security(syminfo.ticker, 'D', h2[1]) 
dtime_h1 = security(syminfo.ticker, 'D', h1[1]) 
dtime_l1 = security(syminfo.ticker, 'D', l1[1]) 
dtime_l2 = security(syminfo.ticker, 'D', l2[1]) 
dtime_l3 = security(syminfo.ticker, 'D', l3[1]) 
dtime_l4 = security(syminfo.ticker, 'D', l4[1]) 
dtime_l5 = security(syminfo.ticker, 'D', l5[1]) 
dtime_l6 = security(syminfo.ticker, 'D', l6[1]) 

// Draw lines for pivit, h1-h6 and l1-l6 ONLY for the current day.
pivotLine = line.new(x1=startTime,y1=dtime_pivot,x2=endTime,y2=dtime_pivot,xloc = xloc.bar_time,extend=extend.none,color=color.yellow,style=line.style_dotted,width=5)

h6Line = line.new(x1=startTime,y1=dtime_h6,x2=endTime,y2=dtime_h6,xloc=xloc.bar_time,extend=extend.none,color=color.red,style=line.style_dotted,width=5)
h5Line = line.new(x1=startTime,y1=dtime_h5,x2=endTime,y2=dtime_h5,xloc=xloc.bar_time,extend=extend.none,color=color.red,style=line.style_dotted,width=4)
h4Line = line.new(x1=startTime,y1=dtime_h4,x2=endTime,y2=dtime_h4,xloc=xloc.bar_time,extend=extend.none,color=color.red,style=line.style_dotted,width=3)
h3Line = line.new(x1=startTime,y1=dtime_h3,x2=endTime,y2=dtime_h3,xloc=xloc.bar_time,extend=extend.none,color=color.red,style=line.style_dotted,width=2)
//h2Line = line.new(x1=startTime,y1=dtime_h2,x2=endTime,y2=dtime_h2,xloc=xloc.bar_time,extend=extend.none,color=color.red,style=line.style_dotted,width=1)
//h1Line = line.new(x1=startTime,y1=dtime_h1,x2=endTime,y2=dtime_h1,xloc=xloc.bar_time,extend=extend.none,color=color.red,style=line.style_dotted,width=5)

l6Line = line.new(x1=startTime,y1=dtime_l6,x2=endTime,y2=dtime_l6,xloc=xloc.bar_time,extend=extend.none,color=color.green,style=line.style_dotted,width=5)
l5Line = line.new(x1=startTime,y1=dtime_l5,x2=endTime,y2=dtime_l5,xloc=xloc.bar_time,extend=extend.none,color=color.green,style=line.style_dotted,width=4)
l4Line = line.new(x1=startTime,y1=dtime_l4,x2=endTime,y2=dtime_l4,xloc=xloc.bar_time,extend=extend.none,color=color.green,style=line.style_dotted,width=3)
l3Line = line.new(x1=startTime,y1=dtime_l3,x2=endTime,y2=dtime_l3,xloc=xloc.bar_time,extend=extend.none,color=color.green,style=line.style_dotted,width=2)
//l2Line = line.new(x1=startTime,y1=dtime_l2,x2=endTime,y2=dtime_l2,xloc=xloc.bar_time,extend=extend.none,color=color.green,style=line.style_dotted,width=1)
//l1Line = line.new(x1=startTime,y1=dtime_l1,x2=endTime,y2=dtime_l1,xloc=xloc.bar_time,extend=extend.none,color=color.green,style=line.style_dotted,width=5)
```

Comment: Can anyone please provide answer to my above question? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The script in Pinescript will be executed for each candle in the chart so it's possible that multiple lines may be drawn.

To prevent that, you have to add a condition to draw the lines only once:

```
//Created by GT

//@version=4
study(title="My Test Camarilla Setup", shorttitle="Camarilla", overlay=true)

showDailyPivots = input(true, title="Show Daily Pivots")

//Calculate Camarilla values
pivot = (high + low + close ) / 3.0 
range = high - low
h5 = (high/low) * close 
h4 = close + (high - low) * 1.1 / 2.0
h3 = close + (high - low) * 1.1 / 4.0
h2 = close + (high - low) * 1.1 / 6.0
h1 = close + (high - low) * 1.1 / 12.0
l1 = close - (high - low) * 1.1 / 12.0
l2 = close - (high - low) * 1.1 / 6.0
l3 = close - (high - low) * 1.1 / 4.0
l4 = close - (high - low) * 1.1 / 2.0
h6 = h5 + 1.168 * (h5 - h4) 
l5 = close - (h5 - close)
l6 = close - (h6 - close)

// Calculate x-axis variables to correspond to day's start time and end time.
// Here start time is hardcoded to 09:15am and endtime as 15:30pm (Timings for Indian Markets) 
// These will be used as part of line.new() statements to draw pivot lines on the chart
yearVar = year
monthVar = month
dayVar = dayofmonth
startTime = timestamp(syminfo.timezone,yearVar,monthVar,dayVar,09,15)
endTime = timestamp(syminfo.timezone,yearVar,monthVar,dayVar,15,30)

//Daily Pivots 
dtime_pivot = security(syminfo.ticker, 'D', pivot[1]) 
dtime_h6 = security(syminfo.ticker, 'D', h6[1]) 
dtime_h5 = security(syminfo.ticker, 'D', h5[1]) 
dtime_h4 = security(syminfo.ticker, 'D', h4[1]) 
dtime_h3 = security(syminfo.ticker, 'D', h3[1]) 
dtime_h2 = security(syminfo.ticker, 'D', h2[1]) 
dtime_h1 = security(syminfo.ticker, 'D', h1[1]) 
dtime_l1 = security(syminfo.ticker, 'D', l1[1]) 
dtime_l2 = security(syminfo.ticker, 'D', l2[1]) 
dtime_l3 = security(syminfo.ticker, 'D', l3[1]) 
dtime_l4 = security(syminfo.ticker, 'D', l4[1]) 
dtime_l5 = security(syminfo.ticker, 'D', l5[1]) 
dtime_l6 = security(syminfo.ticker, 'D', l6[1]) 

// Draw lines for pivit, h1-h6 and l1-l6 ONLY for the current day.

// Notice here the new condition
if barstate.islastconfirmedhistory
    pivotLine = line.new(x1=startTime,y1=dtime_pivot,x2=endTime,y2=dtime_pivot,xloc = xloc.bar_time,extend=extend.none,color=color.yellow,style=line.style_dotted,width=5)
    
    h6Line = line.new(x1=startTime,y1=dtime_h6,x2=endTime,y2=dtime_h6,xloc=xloc.bar_time,extend=extend.none,color=color.red,style=line.style_dotted,width=5)
    h5Line = line.new(x1=startTime,y1=dtime_h5,x2=endTime,y2=dtime_h5,xloc=xloc.bar_time,extend=extend.none,color=color.red,style=line.style_dotted,width=4)
    h4Line = line.new(x1=startTime,y1=dtime_h4,x2=endTime,y2=dtime_h4,xloc=xloc.bar_time,extend=extend.none,color=color.red,style=line.style_dotted,width=3)
    h3Line = line.new(x1=startTime,y1=dtime_h3,x2=endTime,y2=dtime_h3,xloc=xloc.bar_time,extend=extend.none,color=color.red,style=line.style_dotted,width=2)
    //h2Line = line.new(x1=startTime,y1=dtime_h2,x2=endTime,y2=dtime_h2,xloc=xloc.bar_time,extend=extend.none,color=color.red,style=line.style_dotted,width=1)
    //h1Line = line.new(x1=startTime,y1=dtime_h1,x2=endTime,y2=dtime_h1,xloc=xloc.bar_time,extend=extend.none,color=color.red,style=line.style_dotted,width=5)
    
    l6Line = line.new(x1=startTime,y1=dtime_l6,x2=endTime,y2=dtime_l6,xloc=xloc.bar_time,extend=extend.none,color=color.green,style=line.style_dotted,width=5)
    l5Line = line.new(x1=startTime,y1=dtime_l5,x2=endTime,y2=dtime_l5,xloc=xloc.bar_time,extend=extend.none,color=color.green,style=line.style_dotted,width=4)
    l4Line = line.new(x1=startTime,y1=dtime_l4,x2=endTime,y2=dtime_l4,xloc=xloc.bar_time,extend=extend.none,color=color.green,style=line.style_dotted,width=3)
    l3Line = line.new(x1=startTime,y1=dtime_l3,x2=endTime,y2=dtime_l3,xloc=xloc.bar_time,extend=extend.none,color=color.green,style=line.style_dotted,width=2)
    //l2Line = line.new(x1=startTime,y1=dtime_l2,x2=endTime,y2=dtime_l2,xloc=xloc.bar_time,extend=extend.none,color=color.green,style=line.style_dotted,width=1)
    //l1Line = line.new(x1=startTime,y1=dtime_l1,x2=endTime,y2=dtime_l1,xloc=xloc.bar_time,extend=extend.none,color=color.green,style=line.style_dotted,width=5)
```

The condition I've added draws the lines only for the last confirmed candle, for more conditions like this, read the [Documentation](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Bar_states_Built-in_variables_barstate.html).